# How to override List.phtml and Block as well

Tags: magento2, frontend, preference

I'm trying to override the List.phtml and its block using preference I tried this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_module::product/list.phtml">
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but its not working for me and the **di** is

```
<preference type="PME\Hideprice\Block\Product\ListProduct"
                    for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct"/>
```

how can I override this Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try below example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Vendor_module::product/list.phtml </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: and what about the block(ListProduct.php) to override??

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" 
            type="TestApp\Blog\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>`

Add inside etc/frontend/di.xml, create TestApp\Blog\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct class and method that you want to override